# HTML Forms to query multiple pages

Tags: php, html, forms, search-engine

i am trying to build a meta search engine.

I currently have the following code.

```
<form method="POST" action="google_basic.php"> 
<label for="service_op">Service Operation</label><br/>
 <input name="service_op" type="radio" value="Web" CHECKED />
 Web <input name="service_op" type="radio" value="Image" />
 Image <br/> <label for="query">Query</label><br/>
 <input name="query" type="text" size="60" maxlength="60" 
 value="" /><br /><br /> <input name="bt_search" type="submit"
  value="Search" /> </form> <h2>Results</h1> 
  {RESULTS}
```

I need the form to have more than one action= ""(I realise a form can only have one action, i need the equivalent of 3 actions ="" ). The form needs to access 3 search engines and display the results. What is the best way to do this?? I know that javascript may an option but is not a solution for me as it may be switched off in the clients browser.

Any ideas on the best way to go about this??

TIA

Comment: Read up on AJAX techniques.

Comment: OP doesn't want JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform the 3 "actions" on the server (in or from the `google_basic.php` file).  After POSTing to the server, you can perform an arbitrary number of "actions" from there.

See also: https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php

Answer (score 1):

it only needs one action, then the action is what will display all 3 searches. so instead of having google_search.php, bing_search.php, and yahoo_search.php, combine them all into a generic search page that will display all 3